# Undefined reference using the mysql c++ connector

Tags: c++, mysql, linux, ubuntu-18.04

I'm trying to use the mySQL c++ connector.
I have downloaded and extracted the binaries following the mysql guide https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-cpp/8.0/en/connector-cpp-installation-binary.html

When i include the xdevapi like so

```
#include <mysqlx/xdevapi.h>
```

I get the following errors

> /tmp/cc6dzD4k.o: In function `mysqlx::string::operator std::__cxx11::basic_string, std::allocator >abi:cxx11 const':
>
> /git_repos/FHM/Camera/Software/ExtractMetadata/Build/Linux/../../../mysql-connector-c++-8.0.13/include/mysqlx/devapi/common.h:115: undefined reference to `mysqlx::string::Impl::to_utf8[abi:cxx11](mysqlx::string const&)'
>
> /tmp/cc6dzD4k.o: In function `mysqlx::DbDoc::DbDoc()':
>
> /git_repos/FHM/Camera/Software/ExtractMetadata/Build/Linux/../../../mysql-connector-c++-8.0.13/include/mysqlx/devapi/document.h:153: undefined reference to `vtable for mysqlx::DbDoc'
>
> /tmp/cc6dzD4k.o: In function `mysqlx::DbDoc::~DbDoc()':
>   /git_repos/FHM/Camera/Software/ExtractMetadata/Build/Linux/../../../mysql-connector-c++-8.0.13/include/mysqlx/devapi/document.h:127: undefined reference to`vtable for mysqlx::DbDoc'
>
> /tmp/cc6dzD4k.o: In function `mysqlx::Value::print(std::ostream&) const':
>   /git_repos/FHM/Camera/Software/ExtractMetadata/Build/Linux/../../../mysql-connector-c++-8.0.13/include/mysqlx/devapi/document.h:507: undefined reference to`mysqlx::common::Value::print(std::ostream&) const'
>
> /tmp/cc6dzD4k.o:(.rodata._ZTCN6mysqlx5ValueE0_NS_6common5ValueE[_ZTVN6mysqlx5ValueE]+0x18): undefined reference to `typeinfo for mysqlx::common::Value'
>   /tmp/cc6dzD4k.o:(.rodata._ZTCN6mysqlx5ValueE0_NS_6common5ValueE[_ZTVN6mysqlx5ValueE]+0x20): undefined reference to`mysqlx::common::Value::print(std::ostream&) const'
>
> /tmp/cc6dzD4k.o:(.rodata._ZTIN6mysqlx5ValueE[_ZTIN6mysqlx5ValueE]+0x28): undefined reference to `typeinfo for mysqlx::common::Value'
>
> collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
>
> Makefile:2: recipe for target 'x86' failed
>
> make: *** [x86] Error 1

My Makefile look like this:

```
g++ -I../../Src -I../../../Fee/Src \
-I/../../../OpenCV/include/opencv \
-I../../../OpenCV/include/opencv2 \
-I../../../mysql-connector-c++-8.0.13/include/ \
-L../../../OpenCV/lib/LinX86 \
-L../../../mysql-connector-c++-8.0.13/lib64/libmysqlcppconn8-static.a -lssl -lcrypto -lpthread \
-g -D LINUX -o extractmetadata ../../Src/extractMetadata.cpp ../../../Fee/Src/Status.cpp \
-std=c++11 \
-lopencv_world -lstdc++fs \
```

Does anyone know what I'm missing here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are not linking with the MySQL library:

```
-L../../../mysql-connector-c++-8.0.13/lib64/libmysqlcppconn8-static.a
```

Use:

```
../../../mysql-connector-c++-8.0.13/lib64/libmysqlcppconn8-static.a
```

or:

```
-L../../../mysql-connector-c++-8.0.13/lib64/ -lmysqlcppconn8-static
```

Comment: Thank you, but still the same error unfortunately. I have updated the question as it was a bit difficult to see the error message

If I try to use the last alternative I get 

"g++: error: =lmysqlcppconn8-static: No such file or directory"

Comment: Oops, sorry, that was a typo, it's `-`, not `=`.

Comment: Got it working eventually when I found out that I also had version 1.0 of openssl while I needed version 1.1.

Comment: @eirikaso How did you actually do the update? On my Ubuntu 18.04 machine the command ```openssl version``` returns ```OpenSSL 1.1.1 11 Sep 2018```, however in the lib-directory, I find ```/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/openssl-1.0.0```.

Comment: @ctenar Sorry, It's a long time ago and I don't remember. The PC i did it on has also been formatted