# trouble with installation of MySql C++ connector 8 on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: c++, mysql, ubuntu

I am trying to get started with the MySql Connector for C++ on Ubuntu 18.04.
After downloading the debian packages

```
libmysqlcppconn7_8.0.19-1ubuntu18.04_amd64.deb
libmysqlcppconn7-dbgsym_8.0.19-1ubuntu18.04_amd64.deb
libmysqlcppconn8-2_8.0.19-1ubuntu18.04_amd64.deb
libmysqlcppconn8-2-dbgsym_8.0.19-1ubuntu18.04_amd64.deb
libmysqlcppconn-dev_8.0.19-1ubuntu18.04_amd64.deb
```

from the official MySql pages, https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/cpp/8.0.html
I issued the commands

```
sudo apt install ./libmysqlcppconn7-dbgsym_8.0.19-1ubuntu18.04_amd64.deb
sudo apt install ./libmysqlcppconn8-2-dbgsym_8.0.19-1ubuntu18.04_amd64.deb
sudo apt install ./libmysqlcppconn-dev_8.0.19-1ubuntu18.04_amd64.deb
```

based on the assumption that the packages with debug symbols (dbgsym) contain everything, which is why it should be
sufficient to install those. **Is this assumption correct or do I need to install the remaining
packages as well?**

When I look for the respective headers and libs on the filesystem, I find

```
> cd /usr/include/mysql-cppconn-8; ls
jdbc  mysql  mysqlx
> ls mysqlx
common  common_constants.h  common.h  devapi  xapi.h  xdevapi.h
```

etc. and

```
> cd /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu; ls *cppconn*
libmysqlcppconn8.so    libmysqlcppconn8.so.2.8.0.19  libmysqlcppconn.so    libmysqlcppconn.so.7.8.0.19
libmysqlcppconn8.so.2  libmysqlcppconn8-static.a     libmysqlcppconn.so.7  libmysqlcppconn-static.a
```

Still I cannot even compile a minimalistic source file that includes
a single header from mysqlx (e.g. `#include <mysqlx/xdevapi.h>)`, but end up with a bunch of linker errrors.
I tried to adapt what is said here
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-cpp/8.0/en/connector-cpp-apps-general-considerations.html#connector-cpp-apps-tools

to my setting, that is, I tried compilation commands like the following

```
g++ -I/usr/include -I/usr/include/mysql-cppconn-8 -I/usr/include/mysql-cppconn-8/mysqlx -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -lmysqlcppconn8 mysqlcnntest.cpp -o cnntest
```

but that gives a very lengthy linkage error, the beginning of which reads

```
/tmp/ccJwmw6k.o: In function `mysqlx::abi2::r0::string::traits<char>::to_str[abi:cxx11](mysqlx::abi2::r0::string const&)':
mysqlcnntest.cpp:(.text._ZN6mysqlx4abi22r06string6traitsIcE6to_strB5cxx11ERKS2_[_ZN6mysqlx4abi22r06string6traitsIcE6to_strB5cxx11ERKS2_]+0x2e): undefined reference to `mysqlx::abi2::r0::string::Impl::to_utf8[abi:cxx11](mysqlx::abi2::r0::string const&)'
```

Does anyone have any suggestions what I could do to get this working? I'll happily provide any other information you may need to advise. Many thanks in advance!!

Comment: Look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53044235/undefined-reference-using-the-mysql-c-connector).  One of the errors in that thread was identical to your linker error.  The resolution was to use a different, newer OpenSSL library.

Comment: Thank you, but apparently I have the latest version of OpenSSL (1.1.1).